# Why my Dockerfile is not working with my Golang app?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am making a web app based in Golang, and I want to reply it in Docker.

My directory is:

```
-Dockerfile
app/
    -main.go
    /controllers (go code)
    /core (go code)
    /domain (go code)
    /repositories (go code)
media/
    /css
    /html
    /img
    /svg
```

I am following this tutorial: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/complete-guide-to-create-docker-container-for-your-golang-application-80f3fb59a15e

And I have my Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Copy the files into the container (HTML, CSS, images...)
COPY . /media/

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY app/go.mod .
COPY app/go.sum .
RUN go mod download

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 8040

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

And when I try to build the image, I am having an error saying `no Go files in /app`, and I don't know why is that happening, I tried different things but I can not get it working.

I also do not understand why on the second `COPY` I need to put `app/go.mod` or `app/go.sum` when `WORKDIR` is already pointing to `/app` and in the tutorial it is not used, but here I need it to pass that phase in the building image.

The original project is here: https://github.com/kiketordera/full-project-go

Comment: `app/go.mod` and `app/go.sum` is your local workspace, so you're copying those two from your local workspace into `/app` folder of your image

Comment: Yes, I kind of understand that (don't know why I use WORKDIR then), but What I don't get is why I can not build my image, which is my real main problem

Comment: `WORKDIR` is the same as command for changing directory in the shell (like `cd`)

Comment: You go files are at `/app/app`, not `/app`.

Comment: I try with this and is also not working. In any case, there is no sense to have "/app/app". How can I tidy it up and make it work?

Comment: what exactly did you try? you need to use `RUN go build -o main ./app`

Comment: Okkey, I was not putting the `.` before the `/app` , now I put `RUN go build -o main ./app ` and the error is: `main module (github.com/kiketordera/full-project-go/app) does not contain package github.com/kiketordera/full-project-go/app/app`. I tried playing around but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The root problem was that `COPY media .` copies the contents of `media` folder to `/.`
I needed to change `COPY media .` to `COPY media /media/`.
Here is the full Dockerfile solved:

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Copy the code into the container
COPY media /media/

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy the code from /app to the build folder into the container
COPY app .

# Configure the build (go.mod and go.sum are already copied with prior step)
RUN go mod download

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /app

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/app/main"]
```